# jquery script not working untill click action is performed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

Until i click on the div the jquery carousel is not working.

I have added two owl carousel in my html page. It was working fine when i have single carousel but when another carousel is added with different ID it is not working until i perform click inside the div that has carousel.
I have added two owl carousel in my html page. It was working fine when i have single carousel but when another carousel is added with different ID it is not working until i perform click inside the div that has carousel.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            960: {
                items: 5
            },
            1200: {
                items: 6
            }
            }
        });
        owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            960: {
                items: 5
            },
            1200: {
                items: 6
            }
            }
        });
        owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
            owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.owl-carousel-res').owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: true
            },
            600: {
                items: 3,
                nav: false
            },
            1000: {
                items: 6,
                nav: true,
                loop: true,
                margin: 20
            }
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: can you replicate it in a snippet??

Comment: Why are you initializing them on same variable?

Answer (score 0):

> try to use with different ids then both will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
1: Add *"owl-1"* and *"owl-2"* classes to your div with class *"owl-carousel"*
so it becomes `<div class="owl-carousel owl-1">`

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          var owl = $('.owl-1');
          owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsive: {
              0: {
                items: 1
              },
              600: {
                items: 3
              },
              960: {
                items: 5
              },
              1200: {
                items: 6
              }
            }
          });
          owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
              owl.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
              owl.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
          });


          var owl2 = $('.owl-2');
          owl2.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            margin: 10,
            responsive: {
              0: {
                items: 1
              },
              600: {
                items: 3
              },
              960: {
                items: 5
              },
              1200: {
                items: 6
              }
            }
          });
          owl2.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function(e) {
            if (e.deltaY > 0) {
              owl2.trigger('next.owl');
            } else {
              owl2.trigger('prev.owl');
            }
            e.preventDefault();
          });

        });
```